# Casting an object which could be null

Tags: c#, datetime, casting, null

```
DateTime? testDate = (DateTime?)arrayOfObjects[dateObject];
```

Does that code look ok? I attempted to use the `as` operator but I got the 'non-nullable' error. What I'm trying to say is that the object I'm choosing from the array is either `DateTime` or a `null DateTime` but either can be assigned to testDate.

Doesn't feel right doing it this way, I think I'm missing something obvious.

EDIT: I suppose it's the same as the way I could've adapted the `as` in the following way:

```
DateTime? testDate = arrayOfObjects[dateObject] as DateTime?;
```

Is either line of code the best way of handling potential nulls?

Comment: Add the code where arrayOfObjects gets populated...

Comment: It's the result of an SQL query. It's a ResultTableCollection.

Comment: If you can use the debugger, then you could see the type used when breaking after the query result is populated or you add a typeoff call right there. Which DB driver are you using>

Answer (score 4):

> Is either line of code the best way of handling potential nulls?

The second form will silently result in `null` when the array contains something other than a DateTime. That seems a good reason to use the first.

To the basic question:

> am I missing something or is this the typical (or at least an acceptable) approach

It is acceptable but a little obscure maybe, because it is 'hiding' an unboxing operation.
You could use:

```
DateTime? testDate = null;
if (arrayOfObjects[dateObject] != null)  
   testDate = (DateTime) arrayOfObjects[dateObject];  // no '?'
```

But that's verbose. And this particular problem doesn't lend itself well to the conditional operator (`?:`)

So I would stick with your first version.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime? is a shorter form for another struct

```
Nullable<DateTime> {
    bool HasValue;
    DateTime Value;
}
```

You will never get this type from your DB, so the first line will never cast correctly. The database will provide you with a DateTime value stored in an object variable. Or a null (untyped).

DateTime is a struct, so "as" operator won't work for it. So, simply check for null as follows:

```
DateTime? testDate = arrayOfObjects[dateObject] == null ? (DateTime?) null : (DateTime)arrayOfObjects[dateObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to do something like:

```
if(arrayOfObjects[dateObject] != null && arrayOfObjects[dateObject] is DateTime)
{
  DateTime testDate = (DateTime)arrayOfObjects[dateObject];
  // logic here
}
```

or something like:

```
DateTime? testDate = null;
if(arrayOfObjects[dateObject] is DateTime)
{
    testDate = (DateTime)arrayOfObjects[dateObject];
} 
else if (arrayOfObjects[dateObject] is Nullable<DateTime>) 
{
    testDate = (Nullable<DateTime>)arrayOfObjects[dateObject];
}
```

Comment: `DateTime?` is a value type as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Well the problem isn't really with the cast failing, and I don't see the need to necessarily test for null as testDate will accept a null. +1.

Comment: To clarify - my question is - am I missing something or is this the typical (or at least an acceptable) approach to assigning such an object to a nullable DateTime variable?

Comment: @DanielMcNulty Nullable<DateTime> or DateTime? and DateTime are different types.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Array.ConvertAll method. Below is roughly how it is implemented:

```
DateTime?[] dates = Array.ConvertAll<object, DateTime?>arrayOfObjects,DateTime);
```

Note: This is just a rough idea. you can correct it to suit your self.